# Scapy sniff filter tcp with SYN ACK

Tags: python-2.7, scapy

```
pkts=sniff(offline='1.pcap',filter='tcp and tcp.flags.syn==1 and tcp.flags.ack==1')
pkts.summary()
```

nothing is filtered, the output contain all packets, how to filter it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use lfilter with lambda x: x.haslayer(TCP)

```
# TCP-Flags
FIN = 0x01
SYN = 0x02
RST = 0x04
PSH = 0x08
ACK = 0x10
URG = 0x20
ECE = 0x40
CWR = 0x80

pkts=sniff(offline='1.pcap',lfilter = lambda x: x.haslayer(TCP) and x[TCP].flags & SYN and x[TCP].flags & ACK, prn=lambda x:x.summary(), count=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking a [scappy filter usage](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/56d488b4e6711f645f1e3bb7935d00f4d60806e4/doc/scapy/usage.rst#filters), check if the syntax is:

```
pkts=sniff(offline='1.pcap',filter='tcp and tcp.flags.syn 1 and tcp.flags.ack 1')
```

You might need to add a lambda function as well

```
pkts=sniff(offline='1.pcap',filter='tcp and tcp.flags.syn 1 and tcp.flags.ack 1',prn=lambda x:x.summary(), count=10)
```

However, be aware of [issue 5146](https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/issues/5146/sniff-functions-filter-does-not-work-with)

> When a pcap file is specified to sniff function's offline parameter and if filter parameter is provided with proper BPF filter, the sniff does not apply any filter.

That bug is still pending (with a [possible pull request](https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/pull-requests/141/issue-5115/diff)).